# Upload 5 picture with multiple extension in php and sql database

Tags: php

I went to upload picture with any or multiple extension this code work with multiple but give multiple success message

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 

    $target_path = "uploads/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");  //Extensions which are allowed
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//explode file name from dot(.) 
        $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];//set the target path with a new name of image
        $j = $j + 1;//increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

      if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 2097152) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
                && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder
                echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            } else {//if file was not moved.
                echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I went also a sql query which save this names in database

Comment: Please edit your question to include a clear problem statement

Answer (score 2):

The success message span is within the `for` loop, so it prints every time an image is uploaded.

If you want to combine the messages, count success and errors and then, if either count is above 0, print a corresponding error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this part.

```
       if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 2097152) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
                && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder
                exit($j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>');
            }
       } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
                exit($j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>');
       }
    }
    echo $j.' files were uploaded.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 I would try another wat to insert multiple picture extension in my database.



   insert.php
        ------------
            <?php 
                 require "functions.php";

                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                $ext =""; 
                for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['pic']['name']);$i++){
                if ($ext) {
                $ext .= "|";
                 }
                $ext .= Extension($_FILES['pic']['name'][$i]);
                }



                $data = array(
               "picture"=>$ext,
                 );

            if ($id =insert("fm",$data)) {
            if($ext){
            $ext = explode("|", $ext);
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($ext as $e) {
            $dest = "images/".md5($id."-$i-tui-akta-kufa").".$e";
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'][$i-1], $dest);
            $i++;
             }
            }

            echo "Insert successfully";
           }
          else{
          echo "Server too busy";
         }


           }
            else{
       echo "invalid process";
             }

          ?>    




       functions.php
       -----------------
    function Extension($field){
    $mofiz = "";
    if ($field) {
    $mofiz = pathinfo($field);
    $mofiz = strtolower($mofiz['extension']);
        if ($mofiz != "jpg" && $mofiz != "png" && $mofiz != "jpeg" && $mofiz != "gif" 
          ) {
            $mofiz = "";
        }
       }
        return $mofiz;
        }


          form.php
         --------------
              <tr>
            <td>Picture1</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="pic[]" multiple></td>
            </tr>
```